# cmake-ide defining variables

Tags: c++, directory-local-variables

I have a project I build using cmake. To build this project, I need to define several options like `-DPRODUCT=amd64 -DXML_DIR=/opt/xml_database` Normally, I either pass these as -D or configure them in IDEs like qtcreator and vscode. How would I define them in package cmake-ide? I feel like I need to add these to `.dir-local.el` but could not find an example.

Edit: I am trying to edit the variable given in the answer below and it has a type of string. I checked List Variables documentation but can't seem to make it work. In my `dir_local.el`

```
((nil . ((cmake-ide-cmake-args . 
            ("-DSOME_CMAKE1=foo_bar1" "-DSOME_CMAKE2=foo_bar2")
        ))
))
```

but this gives me errors related to type of the variable.`cmake-ide-cmake-args` has type of list of strings. So, how can I edit that variable? I also tried

```
((nil . ((cmake-ide-cmake-args . 
            (list "-DSOME_CMAKE1=foo_bar1" "-DSOME_CMAKE2=foo_bar2")
        ))
))

((nil . ((cmake-ide-cmake-args . 
            `("-DSOME_CMAKE1=foo_bar1" "-DSOME_CMAKE2=foo_bar2")
        ))
))
```

Comment: Note that it's `.dir-locals.el` and _not_ `.dir-local.el` or `dir_local.el`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skimming the source of [`cmake-ide`](https://github.com/atilaneves/cmake-ide) [reveals](https://github.com/atilaneves/cmake-ide/blob/2f3730830c9a01ff08ca82bb3125553f67bb2e4a/cmake-ide.el#L143-L153)

```lisp
(defcustom cmake-ide-cmake-opts
  "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"
  "The options passed to cmake when calling it.  DEPRECATED, use `cmake-ide-cmake-args' instead."
  :group 'cmake-ide
  :safe #'stringp)

(defcustom cmake-ide-cmake-args
  nil
  "The options passed to cmake when calling it."
  :group 'cmake-ide
  :type '(repeat string))
```

So, set `cmake-ide-cmake-args` via `customize`, a `setq`, as a [file variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) or a [directory local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html).

`cmake-ide-cmake-args` should be a list of strings. This isn't clear in its docstring, and is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/atilaneves/cmake-ide/issues/190).

So, if you want to set it via a `.dir-locals.el` you would do something like:

```lisp
;;; Directory Local Variables
;;; For more information see (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")

((nil . ((cmake-ide-build-dir . "/Users/nega/build/foo")
         (cmake-ide-project-dir . "/Users/nega/src/foo")
         (cmake-ide-cmake-args  . ("-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" "-DCMAKE_FOO=BAR")))))
```

Setting it via a `setq` would look like

```lisp
(setq cmake-ide-cmake-args '("-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release"))
```

Comment: Can you show me how to edit this variable of type `'(repeat string)`? I edited the question with further info.